# Show software pyqt5 on two monitors(display) with different images(elements)

Tags: python, image, pyqt5, display, multiple-monitors

I developed a software with Python language and PyQt5 framework. One of the features that I need to implement is that 2 monitors should be connected, the software should be displayed on both monitors, but when selecting an image, in the photo display space, each monitor should display the image in the different color space. For example, one monitor displays the image in gray level and one monitor displays the image in color.
I connect 2 monitors in Windows 10, I set display mode "Extend these displays". I wrote the following code for this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDesktopWidget,QLabel
widget=..... 
display_monitor = 1 # the number of the monitor you want to display your widget
monitor = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(display_monitor)
widget.move(monitor.left(), monitor.top())
```

Now my problem is that the image is displayed on monitor 2, but the main page of the software is displayed only on monitor 1.
I want the home page of the software (or whole software) to be displayed on both monitors, but in the photo display box, each of the monitors will display a separate photo.

Comment: I think that is impossible to do with a reasonable solution, `QWidget` is meant to be under [one screen only](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#screen).

Comment: But this work is done in the software designed with Qt.

Comment: What software? even if your screen is duplicated it is not Qt that is doing this it is the OS.

Comment: Also why do you need to show different information on duplicated screens? What is the use case, Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: I am designing a software for Xray baggage inspection device and this is the main feature of this software. What other solution is there?

Comment: And what is preventing you from creating two widgets?

Comment: Does this mean I have to create QMainWindow twice? Each in the one monitor?
I tried to do this, but unfortunately the program did not run on two monitors. But it was only run on one monitor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246506/discussion-between--and-mery-shadow).